# ETag vs. date in If-Range HTTP header

Tags: http-headers, etag

According to [RFC7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.2), an `If-Range` HTTP header can either be an entity-tag or an HTTP-date.  In this context, section 3.2 of the RFC states

> A valid entity-tag can be distinguished from a valid HTTP-date by
> examining the first two characters for a DQUOTE.

My question: Why do we need *two* characters?  Since weak entity-tags are not allowed here, I would have thought that testing whether the *first* character is a DQUOTE is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would appear to be you do not need to examine two characters, looking at the first character only is sufficient for implementing `If-Range`.

If you look at Apache HTTP Server implementation you can see that it only examines the first character ([http_protocol.c](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/http/http_protocol.c), line 477 at time of writing).

```
if (if_range[0] == '"') {
```

I think the slightly misleading wording of the text can be explained by looking at an earlier version of the HTTP 1.1 specification ([RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-133)) where it says:

> The server can distinguish between a valid HTTP-date and any form of
> entity-tag by examining no more than two characters.

The older statement is not wrong but not immediately relevant to If-Range where only strong ETags are permissible.

I expect the RFC7233 form of the text was an attempt to make the previous text clearer but unfortunately on this occasion it didn't achieve the clarity it sought.